# getting filename from python generator object

Tags: python, generator

I am new to python. I am learning os.walk and yield. If I try to `print(fname)` below it prints a generator object. How do I print the actual file name generated.

```
import os, fnmatch

def locate(pattern, root=os.curdir):

    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.paths.abspath(root)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files,pattern):
            yield os.path.join(path,filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    fname = locate('assert.py')
    print(fname)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    for fname in locate('assert.py')
        print(fname)
```

generators are not evaluated until needed (or iterated)

```
print next(locate("assert.py"),"assert.py not found!")
```

is a way to just get the first match